# How does nickel-browser in Jolicloud launch apps, behind the scenes?

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

For the last few days I've been playing with nickel-browser, Jolicloud's Chromium mod in Ubuntu 10.10. I'm try to create a desktop similar to Jolicloud's, but I've hit a big problem: I can only make it open links. I can't find a way to run commands to launch applications such as Empathy, or a way to open links as a webapp, instead of in a normal browser window.